# While trying to resolve module `idb`

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I have been getting this error since past days,
I have downgraded firebase from 9.8.1 to 9.6.11
but still, it`s been showing the same error

have tried every single solution
but still no progess

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6lYX.png)

Comment: are trying to build a project? start it? which command are you using?

Comment: sorry, didn`t get you

for starting, I am using "Yarn start --clear"

for clearing cache.. and other stuff